# Could NOT find SWIG in Android Studio on Mac M1 Pro

Tags: android, macos, cmake, swig, apple-m1

I have Android project with C++ code and I'm using CMake 3.10, SWIG 4.1 and NDK 20.1.5948944.
On Windows it works fine but on Macbook I have troubles.

I have added environmental variables SWIG_EXECUTABLE, SWIG_DIR.

**Build error:** Could NOT find SWIG (missing: SWIG_EXECUTABLE SWIG_DIR) (Required is at least version "3.0")

**P.S.** If I remove this from build.gradle project builds but C++ feature doesn't work.

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "${projectDir}/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

Comment: how exactly did you install SWIG?

Comment: @starball using brew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find where SWIG is installed:

```
brew info swig
```

Then edit your CMakefiles and set `SWIG_EXECUTABLE` / `SWIG_DIR` accordingly:

```
set(SWIG_EXECUTABLE "swig")
set(SWIG_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/swig/4.1")
```

There is a `FindSWIG` CMake module but it probably doesn't work on macOS : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindSWIG.html

If this is what your project uses, find it, and then set defaults values for those variables just before this line. This way, your project will work on all platforms.

Comment: Seems like problem with SWIG solved, thanks. But I have faced another error:

`Build command failed.
Error while executing process /Users/therxmv/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /Users/therxmv/Documents/MyProject/openvpn/.cxx/cmake/release/arm64-v8a jbcrypto libovpnexec.so opvpnutil osslspeedtest ovpn3}
ninja: Entering directory '/Users/therxmv/Documents/MyProject/openvpn/.cxx/cmake/release/arm64-v8a'`
Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: This is not verbose enough, try to find what is launching `ninja` and try to get a more verbose output. Maybe even try launching it yourself.